# Not Receiving Database Mail from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have database mail setup on SQL Server on a domain. On this domain, I can send to any personal emails, but not a specific PDL (Public Distribution List). The email says sent successfully from SQL Server, but the members of the PDL never receive the email. The team that supports the Exchange server says they never see any attempts to send to that PDL. However, if I use my email account to send to the PDL, I receive it as I should. Any ideas?

Comment: Check the settings for SSL. If you're using Exchange and a PDL I pretty sure you need to use SSL.

Comment: It was off, but I turned it on and it made no difference. I'm wondering if it's an authentication issue of some sort.

Comment: Is the service broker active in msdb?

Comment: I know this doesn't help that much, but in the past when I've had this issue it was the result of an AD configuration issue.